# Unable to delete by id in CosmosDB from spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I'm able to delete the document in cosmosdb using the below code.

```
Optional<Place> place = repository.findById(id);
repository.delete(place.get());
```

But, if I use the method `repository.deleteById(id)` from the `CrudRepository` it's returning me the below error.

```
com.azure.data.cosmos.NotFoundException: ["Resource Not Found"]
```

Comment: Can you include some code here?

Comment: Optional<Place> place= repository.findById(id);

Comment: @KarthikBashyam - please edit your question to include relevant code (and please include more than just a single line, as there's really not enough to go on: maybe include relevant data, as well as your code you're using for deleting a document (your comment only shows how you looked up a document). Please avoid putting code within comments; it's harder to read your question this way, and also it's very difficult to properly format code when it's posted as a comment.

Comment: Hello David. Updated the code.

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the partition key to the deleteById method. Use the following method from CosmosRepository:

```
void deleteById(ID id, PartitionKey partitionKey);
     yourRepository.deleteById(id,new PartitionKey(<parition key value>));
```

The following works because the the argument has the ID and Partition key values.

```
repository.delete(place.get());
```

Additionally, Use the following method from CosmosRepository for find a document by ID.

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id, PartitionKey partitionKey);
```

If your IDs are not unique across partitions then you might get inconsistent results.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. It worked.

Comment: Cool! Please accept the answer. It will help others too. :)